# How can I get connected via SSH in Putty?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, putty, ssh-keys

Vagrant ssh from the machine itself works. All I have to type into the machine is vagrant as a username and I got in the vagrant built machine.

I have to put inside here `vagrant ssh` and it works also from the CMD and PHPStorm terminal.

When I type `Vagrant ssh-config` into CMD or terminal inside PHPSTORM.

```
Host default
HostName 127.0.0.1
User vagrant
Port 2222
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking no
PasswordAuthentication no
IdentityFile C:/Users/nebojsa/.vagrant.d/boxes/richdynamix-VAGRANTSLASH-magestead-centos65-nginx-php56/1.0.2/virtualbox/vagrant_private_key
IdentitiesOnly yes
LogLevel FATAL
```

Then I go in putty and add all of those fields
[image]

This is my vagrant_private_key
[image]

And mostly important 
[image]

I have even tried as passwords in Putty 'vagrant' and it says access denied. 
I don't know what the password is. 
It doesn't work from putty and what am I doing wrong ? 
Is it because of the SSH1 and SSH2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try this [Connect to Your Vagrant Virtual Machine withPuTTY](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/wiki/Connect-to-Your-Vagrant-Virtual-Machine-with-PuTTY)
?

Comment: I didn't know that Putty doesn't work with OpenSSH format. Thanks for a quick response.